# Call public method of class inline php

Tags: php, class

I have `CHtmlPurifier` class with `purify` public method.
This is general usage:

```
<?php $obj = new CHtmlPurifier(); ?>
<?php echo $obj->purify($text); ?>
```

Now, How can I use `purify` method inline?!

Naturally I can not use be like this:

```
<?php echo CHtmlPurifier::purify($text); ?>
```

Because `purify` is not static method.

Another way I try this:

```
<?php echo (new CHtmlPurifier())->purify($text); ?>
```

But this does not work. (I try in PHP 5.3)

Do you have any suggest for use quickly inline without define extra variable?

Comment: Which version of php are you using? last example should work since php5.4

Comment: You can simply pass in an instance of the class to the view(or whereever it is you're outputing the html).

Comment: @rray I try in PHP 5.3

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Yii so can create a service for that and register an instance of CHtmlPurifier on there.
See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-di-servicelocator.html[Yii DI]

If not

you can create new class like this :

```
Class Registery
{
    public static $refs = [];

    public static function get($name)
    {
        if (!isset(self::$refs[$name])) {
            if (class_exists($name)) {
                self::$refs[$name] = new $name();
            } else {
                throw new \Exception('class not exists');
            }
        }

        return self::$refs[$name];
    }

}
```

and you can use it :

```
<?php echo Registery::get('CHtmlPurifier')->purify($text); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I thinks your solution is complex. and so you refers to yii2 work with php 5.4+ but I talk about php 5.3 [be har hal mamnon az masokhet! ;-) ]